# Wordpress - WooCommerce Custom Field Searching

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Wordpress with WooCommerce. I've got this code which works (it was added to my 'functions.php' file).

```
/* add custom search options for Woocommerce */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_order_total' );

function woocommerce_shop_order_search_order_total( $search_fields )
{
  $search_fields[] = 'SERIAL_NUMBER';
  return $search_fields;
}
```

SERIAL_NUMBER is a custom field I enter per product sold manually.
The searching is working, but I have yet another serial that I sometimes search called "DATE_CODE".

How can I search for both?

I tried using:

```
$search_fields[] = 'SERIAL_NUMBER' + 'DATE_CODE';
```

But that didn't work because I assume it was searching for a serial number plus a date code in a single string combination (which isn't what I'm after). I'm after a method where I can search for either one :)

Thanks.

Comment: You just have to add both custom field into the `$search_fields` array, with something like that :

`$search_fields[] = 'SERIAL_NUMBER';
$search_fields[] = 'DATE_CODE';`

Comment: Thanks, that has worked. I thought that would have overwritten the previous `$search_fields` array because it wasn't returned before the next `$search_fields` array.

Comment: We don't do "SOLVED" in the titles here. If you answered your own question you can post it and accept it or delete the question.